# Мягкий scroll помогите реализовать

Tags: javascript

Помогите реализовать мягкий скрол

Вот JS код

```
<script>
   $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) { 
            $('header').addClass("sticky");     
            document.getElementById('menupo').style.display = 'none';       
             document.getElementById("demoform").style.marginLeft = "250px";
             document.getElementById("demoform").style.marginTop = "10px";
        } else {
            $('header').removeClass("sticky");
            document.getElementById('menupo').style.display= 'table';
            document.getElementById("demoform").style.marginTop = "60px";
            document.getElementById("demoform").style.marginLeft = "520px";
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Прошу прещение, за безобразность. Почему то кнопка cod не работает. Если кто исправление отправит, буду рад

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) { 
        $('header').addClass("sticky"); 
        $('#menupo').animate({display:'none'},500);
        $("#demoform").animate({'margin-left':"250px",'margin-top':"10px"},500);
    } else {
        $('header').removeClass("sticky");
        $('#menupo').animate({display:'table'},500);
        $("#demoform").animate({'margin-left':"520px",'margin-top':"60px"},500);
    }
});
```